# Displaying a string representing HMTL as actual HTML, not string content in F#'s Fable application

Tags: html, reactjs, f#, fable-f#, safe-stack

As the title suggests, I'd like to display a string representing some valid HTML as the actual elements the string represents, not to output the string content.

Example: Given the *string* `This <b>is</b> a <em>string</em> representing HTML`, I'd like to see on display: This **is** a *string* representing HTML

I asked somewhere else and got an answer about `unSafeInsideHTML`, a React directive which Fable binds to.
Thing is I've also read online about React's *Fragment* directive which is said to be safer. I can't, though, understand how to use the *Fragment* directive from Fable.

So, is using *Fragment* possible from Fable? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

no idea why wrapping the html elements you're creating in a fragment would make them more secure, but this is how you use Reacts Fragments from F#/Fable.

```
let view model dispatch =
  fragment [ FragmentProp.Key "some key" ] [ 
    td [ ] [ str "1" ]
    td [ ] [ str "1" ]
    td [ ] [ str "1" ]
  ]
```